# Angularjs directive - parsing strings with spaces?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive for facebook feed dialog and I'm trying to add the item title to the directive however I've noticed that angularjs throws the following error whenever {{current_hotel_title}} has spaces in the string:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax Error: Token 'word2' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the expression [word1 word2] starting at [word2].
```

Directive:

```
.directive('fb2Share', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){

        attrs.$observe('fb2Share', function(value) {

            //Directive click handler
            $(element).click(function(){
                scope.$watch(attrs.fb2Title, openDialog);
            });

            //Open FB feed dialog
            var openDialog = function() {

                console.log(attrs.fb2Title);
            };
        });

    };
})
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-fb2-share data-fb2-title="{{current_hotel_title}}">Share on Facebook</a>
```

If I add single quotes over the current hotel title:

```
data-fb2-title="'{{current_hotel_title}}'"
```

the error no longer appears but then I have the problem of single quotes appearing when they are not wanted under the FB share dialog.

Comment: There are several issues with the code that will be easy to clean up. But we could really narrow the answer down concisely if you could explain the intended functionality of your code.  Like - where does `current_hotel_title` come from and what changes it? Is it ng-model in an input? I'm really wondering why the `$watch` is in a click binding which is in an `$observe` that is observing an empty attribute?

Comment: current_hotel_title comes from a controller which is just a string. This value changes in the controller when the user clicks on a different item. You're right about the $observe point. What's the best way to grab attribute values from the directive? When the user clicks on the link I simply want to get all the relevant details from the directive attributes so I can fire a Facebook feed dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to see the interpolated attribute value, then all you need is:

```
attrs.$observe('fb2Title', function(value){
    console.log(value);
    // or
    console.log(attrs.fb2Title);   
}
```

But in your case, you could just use a simple `ng-click` on your button/href.  The ng-click would pass the {{current_hotel_title}} as a parameter to the click function.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="myClickFunction(current_hotel_title)">GO</a>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XqzPVKJFRlZKYYlPGrCr?p=preview)

In reality, you probably don't even need a directive - just put the click handler in the controller.

Comment: What do you do when you have multiple attributes for that directive that you want to check? Do you need to repeat the above? Also how do you check to make sure a value exists for all attributes before calling a function?